# WebLogic: Getting Standard Error Into A File

Tags: logging, weblogic, stdout, standards, out

I'm using WebLogic 9.2. I found an option in the Admin Server web page to send standard out to the server log files. I would like the same for standard error, but I can't find an option for it in the Admin Server web page. I haven't found Oracles documentation very clear.  Do I need to set this option by hand in a config file somewhere and if so where and how?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 'RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled' feature as described in http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/RedirectJVMOutput.html it will redirect both stdout and stderr to the server logs

WebLogic also supports -Dweblogic.stdout=/tmp/mystdout.log & -Dweblogic.stderr=/tmp/mystderr.log properties which you can pass in when starting the server. However note that there is no log rotation for such logs.

Comment: Hi Prash, thanks for taking the time out of your day to answer my question.  I haven't found that to be the case.  I do get stdout to the domain and server log now, but not stderr....either explicit messages I send or stack traces.

Comment: Yes.  I tried   JAVA_OPTIONS= "${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.Stderr=/apps1/bea/existing.log   in the startWebLogic.sh    I don't get any results ( yes, I restarted weblogic )