# How to show Java.Util Logger output in Weblogic?

Tags: web-applications, weblogic, java.util.logging

The Logger was used in internal jars, I saw in some Weblogic docs that it is possible to view Log4j logger output.

How to view the import java.util.logging.Logger output?

I done what mentioned in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/logging_services.htm#WLLOG199

I created logger.properties and run the -Djava command but I still not able to view Logger logs.

```
# Specify the handlers to create in the root logger
handlers = weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler

# Register handlers for the com.foo.toyshop and its child loggers
com.foo.toyshop.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler

# Do not send the toyshop log messages to the root handler
com.foo.toyshop.useParentHandlers = false

# Set the default logging level for the root logger
.level = ALL

# Set the default logging level for new ConsoleHandler instances
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO

# Set the default logging level for new FileHandler instances
weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler.level = ALL
```

[update]

For some reason I can only see the Logger output in the WL process prints (./startWL.sh) and not in the log

Comment: Did you sent it to a file? Have you turned on both stderr and stdout going to the log file via the admin console? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957893/weblogic-getting-standard-error-into-a-file or http://tim.blackamber.org.uk/?p=596

Comment: Yes, I had to remove the cache and restart WL, now it's working

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with Log4j or Commons Logging, Weblogic supports both and it's explained here: [Log4j and the Commons Logging API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/config_logs.htm#WLLOG144)

In the same [guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/toc.htm) you could find the steps needed to work with logging and Weblogic:

> The following steps summarize how you configure and filter log
>   messages that WebLogic Server generates. Related documentation and
>   later sections in this guide describe these steps in more detail.
>
> 1. Use the Administration Console to manage log files and
>      configure the following logging options:
>
>    1. Domain and
>         server log file name and location, rotation pattern, location of
>         archived log files, and number of log files stored. See "View
>         and configure logs" in the Oracle WebLogic
>         Server Administration Console Help.
>    2. Types of
>         messages that the server sends to standard out. See "Specify
>         messages for standard out" in the Oracle
>         WebLogic Server Administration Console Help.
>    3. Which messages a server instance sends to the domain log. See "Forward
>         messages to the domain log" in the Oracle
>         WebLogic Server Administration Console Help.
>    4. Log files for HTTP requests. See "Enable
>         and configure HTTP logs" in the Oracle
>         WebLogic Server Administration Console Help.
>    5. Specify the logging implementation (Java Logging or Log4j). See How to Use Log4j with WebLogic Logging
>         Services.
>    6. Specify message destination and
>         configure filtering log messages by severity level or other criteria.
>         See "Filter
>         log messages" in the Oracle WebLogic Server
>         Administration Console Help. See also Specifying Severity Level for Loggers.
> 2. Alternatively, configure log message filtering on
>      the message handler using the WebLogic Scripting Tool. See "Configuring
>      Existing Domains" in Oracle WebLogic
>      Scripting Tool.
> 3. Filter log messages published
>      by the logger using the Java APIs. See Filtering Messages by Severity Level or
>      Other Criteria.